# Добавление виджетов в PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Допустим, есть такой код. В функции MyFunction должен создаваться новый виджет. Не важно, с каким положением. Просто приведите пример создания. Я никак в доках откопать не могу функцию создания. 
main.py:

```
import sys
from untitled import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setText('Изначально невидимая кнопка')
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.ui.pushButton_2)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    def MyFunction(self):
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setVisible(True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

untitled.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(564, 349)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае на виджете `QDialog` размещена кнопка `button` при нажатии на которую вызывается функция `print_names` которая делает видимым  кнопку `self.button_1`

Т.е. для того чтобы создать новую кнопку вам нужно объявить переменную и присвоить ей эту [кнопку](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#QPushButton) в данном случае создается 2 кнопки и одну скрытую( чтобы при нажатии несколько раз на `button` не создавалась новая кнопка а про делалась видимой  старая)

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class App(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Тест'
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        button = QPushButton()
        button.setText('Вывод')
        button.clicked.connect(self.print_names)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.button_1 = QPushButton()
        self.button_1.setVisible(False)
        self.button_1.setText('Изначально невидимая кнопка')
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.button_1.setVisible(False))
        layout.addWidget(self.button_1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def print_names(self):
        self.button_1.setVisible(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Нужно поменять атрибут класса `MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow)` на `MyWin(QtWidgets.QWidget)` так как в `QMainWindow` присутствуют проблемы с `Layout`

```
import sys
from untitled import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setText('Изначально невидимая кнопка')
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.ui.pushButton_2)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)

    def MyFunction(self):
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setVisible(True)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Для того чтобы продолжить работу с `QMainWindow` нужно создавать отдельный виджет по типу `QFrame`:

```
import sys
from untitled import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.ui.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setText('Изначально невидимая кнопка')
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.ui.pushButton_2)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.ui.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
    def MyFunction(self):
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setVisible(True)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Использование методом  [`move(x, y)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#move-1) который задает позицию виджета а [`resize(x, y)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resize-1) задает размер самого виджета

```
import sys
from asddddd import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.ui.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setText('Изначально невидимая кнопка')
        self.ui.pushButton_2.resize(200,30)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.move(300, 300)
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MyFunction)
        self.frame.setLayout(self.ui.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
    def MyFunction(self):
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setVisible(True)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: переделал по вашему примеру. Кнопка создается в новом окне....

Comment: Так и есть. Я же с designer'ом делаю.

Comment: setLayout не работает. Пишет, что нет такого аттрибута

Comment: сейчас скину, что у меня на данный момент в коде, а вы поправьте

Comment: скинул код обоих файлов

Comment: @Evilenzo подредактирвал в `untitled.py` ничего не изменялось

Comment: сейчас попробуем

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: А не в Layout'ах можно создавать виджеты?

Comment: можно пример кода?

Comment: @Evilenzo обновил

Comment: c QWidget такое работает?

Comment: @Evilenzo да работает